# How to retrieve hidden elements in inspect element - Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Does anyone here know how to retrieve hidden elements in Chrome Dev Tools Console? Total mentioned elements are almost 400 but 155 are hidden. How to unhide them? [image]

Comment: Next to that hidden # is a filter icon with a string next to it. Are you filtering?

Comment: Since your question does not contain any code, please add the image here.

Comment: @Kinglish yes. I filtered to see if there is any hidden element. Total elements almost 400 but i don't know why 155 are hidden